# VAE with a discriminator compiling problem

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0, autoencoder, generative-adversarial-network

As opposed to native generative models, the input for this vae is a RGB image. Here if I compile the `self.combined` using `add_loss` method, the loss goes around 15000 to -22000. Compiling using `mse` works fine.

```
    def __init__(self,type = 'landmark'):

        self.latent_dim = 128
        self.input_shape = (128,128,3)
        self.batch_size = 1
        self.original_dim = self.latent_dim*self.latent_dim
        patch = int(self.input_shape[0] / 2**4)
        self.disc_patch = (patch, patch, 1)

        optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.0002, 0.5)

        pd = patch_discriminator(type)
        self.discriminator = pd.discriminator()
        self.discriminator.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy',optimizer = optimizer)
        self.discriminator.trainable = False

        vae = VAE(self.latent_dim,type = type)
        encoder = vae.inference_net()
        decoder = vae.generative_net()

        if type == 'image':
            self.orig_out = tf.random.normal(shape = (self.batch_size,128,128,3))
        else:
            self.orig_out = tf.random.normal(shape = (self.batch_size,128,128,1))

        vae_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape = self.input_shape)
        self.encoder_out = encoder(vae_input)
        self.decoder_out = decoder(self.encoder_out[2])

        self.generator = tf.keras.Model(vae_input,self.decoder_out)
        vae_loss = self.compute_loss()
        self.generator.add_loss(vae_loss)
        self.generator.compile(optimizer = optimizer)

        valid = self.discriminator([self.decoder_out,self.decoder_out])
        self.combined = tf.keras.Model(vae_input,valid)
        self.combined.add_loss(vae_loss)
        self.combined.compile(optimizer = optimizer)
        # self.combined.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer)

        self.dl = DataLoader()
```

compute loss computes kl loss for VAE. Initially `self.orig_out` is set as normal tensor and is updated in training loop below.

```
    def compute_loss(self):
        bce = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy()
        reconstruction_loss = bce(self.decoder_out,self.orig_out)
        reconstruction_loss = self.original_dim*reconstruction_loss
        z_mean = self.encoder_out[0]
        z_log_var = self.encoder_out[1]
        kl_loss = 1 + z_log_var - K.square(z_mean) - K.exp(z_log_var)
        kl_loss = K.sum(kl_loss, axis=-1)
        kl_loss *= -0.5
        vae_loss = K.mean(reconstruction_loss + kl_loss)
        return vae_loss
```

Training loop:

```
    def train(self,batch_size = 1,epochs = 10):
        start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        valid = np.ones((batch_size,) + self.disc_patch)
        fake = np.zeros((batch_size,) + self.disc_patch)
        threshold = epochs//10

        for epoch in range(epochs):
            for batch_i,(imA,imB,n_batches) in enumerate(self.dl.load_batch(target='landmark',batch_size=batch_size)):
                self.orig_out = tf.convert_to_tensor(imB, dtype=tf.float32)
                fakeA = self.generator.predict(imA)

                d_real_loss = self.discriminator.train_on_batch([imB,imB],valid)
                d_fake_loss = self.discriminator.train_on_batch([imB,fakeA],fake)
                d_loss = 0.5*np.add(d_real_loss,d_fake_loss)

                combined_loss = self.combined.train_on_batch(imA)
                #combined_loss = self.combined.train_on_batch(imA,valid)

                elapsed_time = datetime.datetime.now() - start_time


                print (f"[Epoch {epoch}/{epochs}] [Batch {batch_i}/{n_batches}] [D loss: {d_loss}] [G loss: {combined_loss}] time: {elapsed_time}")
```

If I compile `self.combined` with kl loss using `add_loss()` method, I am not able to pass outputs during `train_on_batch` as shown above. Thus the generator won't learn and produces random outputs. How do I compile vae with discriminator using kl loss ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this will be the right answer, but VAE can be modeled using Tensorflow more easily since it deals with custom training loops.
You can follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60186806/vae-with-a-discriminator-compiling-problem) which may contain some relevant information for your problem.